# React-query returns Cannot read properties of undefined even though I can see id is set

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, async-await, react-query

I am trying to learn react-query and been following quite a few guides. However everytime I try with parameters something goes wrong.
This code that I have under just keep telling me that Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id') even though the console.log(id) prints out the correct number.

```
const PracticeList = ({id}) => {
    const idTest = id
    conosole.log(idTest) //this prints 190 and is not undefined
  const { isLoading, isFetching, data, isError } = useQuery(["list",{id:idTest}],GetList,{
      retry:1,
      retryDelay:500
  })
    if (isLoading) {
        return <p>Loading</p>
    }
    if (isError) {
        return <p>Error getting posts...</p>
    }
    return (
        <div> {isFetching && <p>Updating</p>}{data &&<p>{data.lists}</p>}</div>
    )
}
```

```
export const GetList = async(key,obj)=>{
    console.log(key,obj) //This prints that key is defined but obj is undefined?

    const {data} = await ShoppingListAPI.get(`/getShoppingList`,{id:obj.id});
    return data;
}
```

This never really happends as it crashes before, but I do know it works from postman.

```
import axios from 'axios';
export default axios.create({
    baseURL:"http://localhost:3005/api/v1/",
});
```

This is where I set the Id btw.

```
import './App.css';
import {Container, Typography} from '@mui/material'
import AllLists from './AllLists';
import { useState } from 'react';
import ShoppingList2 from './ShoppingList2';
import Practice from './Practice';
import PracticeList from './PracticeList';
function App() {
  const [activeList, setActiveList]= useState(190)
  return (
    <div className="App">
        <Typography>Shopping list</Typography>
        <Container maxWidth="lg">
          <Practice/>
          {activeList&&<PracticeList id={activeList}/>}
        
        </Container>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since v3, react-query injects an object called the `QueryFunctionContext` into the queryFn. It contains the queryKey, among other information.

So if your query is:

```
useQuery(["list",{id:idTest}],GetList)
```

you can extract the queryKey in `GetList` via:

```
const GetList = (queryFunctionContext) => {
  const queryKey = queryFunctionContext.queryKey
}
```

`queryKey[0]` will then be `"list"` and `queryKey[1]` should be your object that contains the `id`.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
()=>GetList(idTest)
```

```
const { isLoading, isFetching, data, isError } = useQuery(["list",{id:idTest}],()=>GetList(idTest),{
```

Comment: It dosent return the error anymore, but it didnt really fix my problem considering now the request gets sent without params since {id:obj?.id} dosent send apperntly because of .? it looks like

Comment: And if i try const {data} = await ShoppingListAPI.get(`getShoppingList/${obj?.id}`,{id:obj?.id}); it just responds with GET http://localhost:3005/api/v1/getShoppingList/undefined and that dosent help me much

Comment: Still undefined even with ()=>GetList. I also updated the question incase I did something wrong importing it or if that dosent make sense maybe

Comment: I removed key and than it worked. Well that sucks, thanks for the help

Comment: @Runningmoments do you tried ``()=>GetList(idTest)``with ``idTest``?

Comment: Yes I did, it didnt have a effect. However I am using it now so it works regardless but the key thing was the problem.

Comment: this should work